# Vim HereDoc Highlighting

Tags: bash, vim, syntax-highlighting, heredoc, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to get syntax highlighting inside of a bash heredoc. In addition, I want bash variable dereference and command substitution highlighting in the heredoc.

Using [these instructions](https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/87-smarter-heredoc-syntax-in-vim/) as a starting point, I was able to add variable dereferencing by examining [sh.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/sh.vim). I imagine you could accomplish command substitution in a similar fashion.

```
let s:bcs = b:current_syntax

unlet b:current_syntax
syntax include @YAML syntax/yaml.vim

syntax region hereDocYAML matchgroup=Statement start=/<<-\?\s*\z(YML\)/ end=/^\s*\z1/ contains=@YAML,hereDocDeref,hereDocDerefSimple

syn match  hereDocDerefSimple  "\$\%(\h\w*\|\d\)"
syn region hereDocDeref  matchgroup=PreProc start="\${" end="}"  contains=@shDerefList,shDerefVarArray

hi def link hereDocDeref PreProc
hi def link hereDocDerefSimple PreProc
```

My problem is, this doesn't appear to work in any sort of block (`if`, `function`, `for`, etc.). For example:

[image: highlighting example]

The only thing I know is that this is not an indentation problem. Changing indentation has no effect, and using indentation outside of a block works properly.

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot fathom why someone would vote to close this. It's a question about a programming problem using the programming language which backs a widely-used programming tool.

Comment: There are people who feel all vi/vim question belong on vi.SE, and others who seem to blindly assume all "text editor" issues should go to SU. I disagree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contains` on [the definition of `shIf`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/26e8558e74fc1701b57f092cc2c3dbf879cf1af3/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L243) appears to limit the possible highlights to whatever items are in `shIfList` group.

Adding your item to the group as follows will give you highlighting withing that region:

```
syn cluster shIfList add=hereDocYAML
```

The same principle holds for all other blocks. For example:

```
syn cluster shFunctionList add=hereDocYAML
syn cluster shLoopList     add=hereDocYAML
```

It should be noted that the approach you've outlined is not generally useful. First of all, it requires that the included syntax file use groups for their `contains` definitions.

In addition, it works for YAML because bash dereference syntax and YAML syntax do not conflict. For more complicated syntaxes like sed or awk, you will have conflicts, and the rules to resolve those conflicts will likely require a new syntax entirely.

Comment: I find this Q&A very confusing. The author of the Q and this A are both @tim-pote and yet there is this weird 3rd person thing going on like "the approach you've outlined is not generally useful". Could we please get a concise answer here? I'm not able to infer what part of the Q should be kept and which parts should be replaced by what is in this A.

Comment: What are the odds that I would stumble on this answer almost exactly a year later and read the entire comment above before realizing it was my own? (Well, if you know me, that latter part wouldn't come as a surprise.)